# How do I fix my errors and get my Adyen Drop In Web to work?

Tags: php, css, json, adyen

This is another attempt trying to get Adyen Drop In Web to work. Currently I've got it to work with a Wordpress plugin, on an auto installed Heroku website using Node.js and on my localhost using PHP. Now I'm trying to get it from my localhost to my website for testing, however it's not going well. (In the end I want to have a working Drop In Web PHP version, without framework.)

I'm getting these errors after uploading the files to my website:

https://gyazo.com/4ce6072bd536b60a3fc57ef6d39f6725

My page file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Adyen Checkout Components sample code</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/sdk/3.15.1/adyen.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/Adyen/src/demo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container container--full-width">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="checkout-container">
                <a href="../">Back</a>

                <h1>Drop-in</h1>
                <div class="payment-method">
                    <div id="dropin-container">
                        <!-- Drop-in will be rendered here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <p>
                    Check the Source Code to see the full implementation.
                </p>
                <p>
                    To make a payment, use our <a href="https://docs.adyen.com/developers/development-resources/test-cards/test-card-numbers" target="_blank">test card numbers</a>.
                </p>
                <p>
                    For more information, please refer to the <a href="https://docs.adyen.com/checkout/drop-in-web/" target="_blank">Drop-in documentation</a>.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="header">
                <h2>Basic Implementation</h2>
                <button class="copy-sample-code" aria-label="Copy sample code"></button>
            </div>
            <pre class="source-code">
                <code>
                
                    const checkout = new AdyenCheckout({
                        environment: 'test',
                        clientKey: 'test_...',
                        paymentMethodsResponse: { ... }
                    });
    
                    const dropin = checkout.create('dropin', {
                        onSubmit: (state, dropin) => {}
                    }).mount('#dropin-container');

                </code>
            </pre>

            <div class="header">
                <h2>Current state</h2>
            </div>
            <pre class="current-state">{}</pre>

            <div class="request-container">
                <div class="header">
                    <h2>Request</h2>
                </div>
                <p>The request to the <code>/payments</code> endpoint will be shown here.</p>
                <pre class="request-code"></pre>
            </div>

            <div class="response-container">
                <div class="header">
                    <h2>Response</h2>
                </div>
                <p>The response from the <code>/payments</code> endpoint will be shown here.</p>
                <pre class="response-code"></pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/sdk/3.15.1/adyen.js"></script>
    <script src="/site/Adyen/src/demo.js"></script>
    <script src="/site/Adyen/src/utils.js"></script>
    <script src="/site/Adyen/src/dropin/dropin.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

utils.js file:

```
const paymentMethodsConfig = {
    shopperReference: 'Checkout Components sample code test',
    reference: 'Checkout Components sample code test',
    countryCode: 'NL',
    amount: {
        value: 1000,
        currency: 'EUR'
    }
};

const paymentsDefaultConfig = {
    shopperReference: 'Checkout Components sample code test',
    reference: 'Checkout Components sample code test',
    countryCode: 'NL',
    channel: 'Web',
    returnUrl: 'https://your-company.com/',
    amount: {
        value: 1000,
        currency: 'EUR'
    },
    lineItems: [
        {
            id: '1',
            description: 'Test Item 1',
            amountExcludingTax: 10000,
            amountIncludingTax: 11800,
            taxAmount: 1800,
            taxPercentage: 1800,
            quantity: 1,
            taxCategory: 'High'
        }
    ]
};

// Generic POST Helper
const httpPost = (endpoint, data) =>
    fetch(`/${endpoint}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(response => response.json());

// Get all available payment methods from the local server
const getPaymentMethods = () =>
    httpPost('paymentMethods', paymentMethodsConfig)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.error) throw 'No paymentMethods available';

            return response;
        })
        .catch(console.error);

// Posts a new payment into the local server
const makePayment = (paymentMethod, config = {}) => {
    const paymentsConfig = { ...paymentsDefaultConfig, ...config };
    const paymentRequest = { ...paymentsConfig, ...paymentMethod };

    updateRequestContainer(paymentRequest);

    return httpPost('payments', paymentRequest)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.error) throw 'Payment initiation failed';

            updateResponseContainer(response);

            return response;
        })
        .catch(console.error);
};

// Fetches an originKey from the local server
const getOriginKey = () =>
    httpPost('originKeys')
        .then(response => {
            if (response.error || !response.originKeys) throw 'No originKey available';

            return response.originKeys[Object.keys(response.originKeys)[0]];
        })
        .catch(console.error);

// Fetches a clientKey from the 
const getClientKey = () =>
    httpPost('clientKeys')
        .then(response => {
            if (response.error || !response.clientKey) throw 'No clientKey available';

            return response.clientKey;
        })
        .catch(console.error);
```

**Any help is appreciated.**

Comment: Your error shows that your backend is returning 404s. Otherwise nothing looks glaringly problematic in your client code.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at my code. 
I have close to none experience with json, so I'm not really sure how to adjust my code to get my files from another folder or change the files locations so that the code can find it. Could you point me into the right direction?

Comment: Start smaller, like first make sure /clientKeys can actually return json (using something like curl), once you are certain all your backend apis are working, then add on the client portion. Also use chrome developer tools > network tab to see the requests and response made with your client. You can see what the specific response your server is sending.

Comment: Thanks, I was also using the ProcessWire CMS, I've given what I had to my collaegue and we're gonna look at it together. Going back to the simplest form and testing from there. Haven't struggled with an API like this before. I think I'm in over my head with this one. Thanks alot with all your help.